# Seeing other player nextpeer

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, nextpeer

I successfully integrate nextpeer into my cocos 2d game.
Now i want to show other people playing online using nextpeer.
The problem is i dont know how to do that.The documentation for it is not opening and i even mail nextpeer and they have not respond more than 24 hrs have gone.Can someone give me some advice the steps involve in it.

Here is the link of an app showing it
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chasing-yello/id508314901?mt=8

The nextpeer link which is not opening - 
http://developers.nextpeer.com/documentation/docs?page=iOS+Guide#PlayertoPlayerCommunication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nextpeer document is moved to : https://developers.nextpeer.com/docs/view/ios

Scroll down for PlayertoPlayerCommunication.

Comment: Yes,that helps but i am unable to do in Box 2d game...
Any advise for box 2d?
Any way thanks for your help

Comment: welcome..I just tried simple nextpeer not p2p(player 2 player)version of nextpeer.

Comment: Hi,it took sometime but was succesfull!
It is simple as simple as normal nextpeer integration

Comment: then post your answer...useful to many people..including me :)

Answer (score 1):

These are the two active links for player to player communication now.

https://developers.nextpeer.com/docs/view/ios#PlayertoPlayerCommunication and https://developers.nextpeer.com/docs/view/bestpractice#PlayertoPlayercommunication(P2P).

If you have anymore specific question, feel free to email me directly at alexander@nextpeer.com.

Sorry for the confusion.